# Tcl: default if variable is empty?

Tags: string, tcl

I've "inherited" some Tcl code, and while I worked through some tutorials and can make sense out of the language, my own Tcl constructs lack a certain... finesse.

For example, I have this code:

```
puts "Column 'name': [ $queryRs getString name ]"
```

`$queryRs` is the result set of a SQL query. The `[ $queryRs getString name ]` construct retrieves the content of the table column "name" from the current row in the result set. If the database field is NULL, the `puts` does not print anything.

I would like to print a "default" string instead, i.e. if `[ $queryRs getString name ]` results in nothing, I'd like to replace it with `"--"`.

Now, I could do something like this:

```
set nameVar "[ $queryRs getString name ]"
if { [ string length $nameVar ] == 0 } {
    set nameVar "--"
}
puts "Column 'name': $nameVar"
```

But there **has** to be a more compact solution, something that can be done inline instead of adding four lines and a temporary variable. Help, please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two things.

First, Tcl doesn't have a notion of `NULL` (`nil`, `undefined` or whatever) *value,* and when you want to simulate such a value you have to either use a variable and [test for its existence](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/info.htm#M11) or use an entry in an [`array`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/array) of [`dict`ionary](http://wiki.tcl.tk/dict) and test for its existence, too.  If such a variable/entry exists, then the value is defined, otherwise it's not.

Unfortunately, the creator of your inherited code apparently did not care about the case where a variable can be `NULL` so `NULLs` are indistinguishable from variables having default values (an empty string).

Next, you can use a helper procedure to do what you need:

```
proc ValueOrDef {val {def --}} {
   expr {$val ne "" ? $val : $def}
}
```

and then go like this:

```
puts [ValueOrDef [$queryRs getString name]]
puts [ValueOrDef [$queryRs getString name] "some other default"]
```

Comment: Ah... I knew about default parameters, but didn't make the connection to feeding `name` through a function like that. Thanks, this is what I've been looking for.

Comment: Well, the function is not strictly needed -- you can get away just by using `expr` and its ternary conditional operator as @bmk suggested; a specialized function just makes the intent clearer.

Comment: Yes, but it's generally better to make the definition complex and the usage simple than the other way around.

Comment: Uh... does Tcl actually *have* something like "ne"? I had to replace `$val ne ""` with `[string length $val] > 0` to get your code running...

Comment: @DevSolar, sure [it does](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/expr.htm#M14), just you have Tcl older than 8.4 and this means it's older than dust -- see [the timeline](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1721). Note that 8.4 is unmaintained and 8.6 is close to be released.  If possible, consider upgrading to 8.5.

Comment: Strictly, there will be exactly one more patch release of 8.4, which will be put out once 8.6.0 is released. It will fix a number of bugs that it happened to be reasonably easy to backport a fix for (I'd have to check the repository to see exactly what).

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `x?y:z` construct of the `expr` command. `x` is the condition, `y` is the alternative if the condition is met and `z` is the alternative if `x` is not met.

E.g. (but still with a temporary variable):

```
set nameVar [ $queryRs getString name ]
puts "Column 'name': [expr {[string length $nameVar]>0 ? $nameVar : "--"}]"
```

Comment: One liners are always preferred +1